# React Native - Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected string but got: undefiend

Tags: javascript, react-native, undefined, invariants

So when I use this code everything works just fine:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback, KeyboardAvoidingView, SimpleAnimation, Text, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import FlatButton from './button';

const thirdColor = 'red'; 
const secColor = 'blue'; 
const mainColor = 'green'; 

export default class ImagePickerExample extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    image: null,
  };

  return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Button
      title="Pick an image from camera roll"
      onPress={this._pickImage}
    />
    {image &&
      <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
  </View>
);
...
```

After that, everything I change is inside my redner() method and the code looks so:

```js
   ...

export default class ImagePickerExample extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    image: null,
  };

  render() {
    let { image } = this.state;

    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
        //whenever touched the soroundings, keyboard will be dismissed
        Keyboard.dismiss();
      }}>
  
      <View style={styles.container}>
  
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='position'>
  
        <SimpleAnimation delay={500} duration={1200} fade staticType='bounce'>
          <Text style={{color: thirdColor, fontSize: 61}}>Welcome back</Text>
        </SimpleAnimation>

        {image &&
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._pickImage}>
          <Ionicons name="ios-person" size={100} color={thirdColor} ></Ionicons>
        </TouchableOpacity>} 
  
        <SimpleAnimation delay={600} duration={1200} fade staticType='bounce'>
        <View style={styles.contYourName}>
        <TextInput placeholder='Username' style = {styles.yourName}></TextInput>
        </View>
        </SimpleAnimation>
  
        <SimpleAnimation delay={900} duration={1200} fade staticType='bounce'>
        <View style={styles.regButtonView}>
        <FlatButton text='finsih' onPress={alert}/>
        </View>
        </SimpleAnimation>
  
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  
      </View>
  
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}

...
```

After I did this I get following error message on my iPhone through Expo:

[error code from IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtqtA.jpg)

What is wrong with it? My current React Native version is:

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.61.4

EDIT:
Here are the functions:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.getPermissionAsync();
    console.log('hi');
  }

  getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    if (Constants.platform.ios) {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
      }
    }
  }

  _pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
    }
  };
```

Another EDIT:

As soon as I comment all `<SimpleAnimation></SimpleAnimation>` than everything works again. Why is `<SimpleAnimation></SimpleAnimation>` a problem?

Comment: did you import all component you used ???

Comment: @TwinklePatel yeah I did

Answer (score 1):

change image state to "" (empty String) instead of null or handle null condition of image uri;

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback, KeyboardAvoidingView, SimpleAnimation, Text, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import FlatButton from './button';

const thirdColor = 'red'; 
const secColor = 'blue'; 
const mainColor = 'green'; 

export default class ImagePickerExample extends React.Component {

  state = {
    image: "",
  };

  return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Button
      title="Pick an image from camera roll"
      onPress={this._pickImage}
    />
    {image &&
      <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I tested it but it did not work..I get the same error message

Comment: I eddited them into my post on the bottom. But I dont think that those methods would be the problem because the first code works and the second one not and the only thing I changed is the render() method

Comment: so I just found this out: As soon as I comment all `<SimpleAnimation></SimpleAnimation>` than everything works again. Why is `<SimpleAnimation></SimpleAnimation>` a problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check all methods are imported which you have used.
2. use this.state.image instead of image.
3. Rerun or reload

Comment: so I tried it but still the same error. I replaced my whole render with that first code again and it worked. But as soon as I change the content of my render method back, i get the error again

Comment: so I just found this out: As soon as I comment all `<SimpleAnimation></SimpleAnimation>` than everything works again. Why is `<SimpleAnimation></SimpleAnimation>` a problem?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was the `<SimpleAnimation></SimpleAnimation>` tags in my render(). Thats because somehow this import got messed up. So I did the following that fixed my problem:

1. `npm uninstall react-native-simple-animations`
2. `npm install react-native-simple-animations`
3. After that import in your code with: `import { SimpleAnimation } from 'react-native- simple-animations';` dont forget the `{ }`